# d3 Choropleth map with different dates and times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I created my own Germany.json with administrative regions.

As data for this Germany.json, I created a simple table with 2 columns: 
(Name of administrative region)(Rate of administrative region)

My map works great, but my job isn't done with that.

I have detailed tables with 4 columns (Date, Time, Administrative region and a rate).

So the Choropleth map can be created if you choose a date first, then a time. After choosing a date and time, the map for the given input shows up.

The problem here, is that I'm a beginner in Javascript. 
I have some ideas in my mind, but I can't move the ideas into code.

That's why I ask here for help and ideas.

Is what I'm asking about even possible?

http://www.vincentbroute.fr/mapael/usecases/world/

The map at above link is the most interesting Choropleth map I have found so far that has something in common with the map I want to make.

Thanks for reading this far.

Here is my code:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.properties {
  fill: none;
}

//Hier werden die Farben für verschiedene Kategorien zugeteilt
.q0-9 { fill:rgb(247,251,255); }
.q1-9 { fill:rgb(222,235,247); }
.q2-9 { fill:rgb(198,219,239); }
.q3-9 { fill:rgb(158,202,225); }
.q4-9 { fill:rgb(107,174,214); }
.q5-9 { fill:rgb(66,146,198); }
.q6-9 { fill:rgb(33,113,181); }
.q7-9 { fill:rgb(8,81,156); }
.q8-9 { fill:rgb(8,48,107); }



</style>

<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
 
    
//Größe der Karte wird eingestellt
var width = 1050,
 height = 1000;
 
var rateById = d3.map();
//Skalierung für die Einfärbung 
var quantize = d3.scale.quantize()
    .domain([1, 50])
    .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));
 
//Skalierung und Ausrichtung auf deutschland
var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([10.4, 51.35])
    .rotate([1, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * 5)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
//D3 Projection wird angelegt
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);


//svg wird angelegt
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
//Warteschlange zum Ausführen des Skripts wird angelegt
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "germany.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "test2.tsv", function(d) { 
  rateById.set(d.NAME_2, +d.rate); 
  })
    .await(ready);

//Karte wird geladen und mit den gewünschten Properties geöffnet und zugewiesen   
function ready(error, de) {
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "properties")
    svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(de, de.objects.collection).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { 
  return quantize(rateById.get(d.properties.NAME_2)); 
   })
      .attr("d", path);


}

//d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
</script>
```

Comment: // , Not to be *that guy*, but isn't it called "Choropleth", from the Greek χωροπληθών?

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is your problem? Where exactly are you stuck?

To get you started, you might want to check out [**this simple demo app**](http://johnslegers.com/map/) I built a while ago. When selecting one of seven datasets, it loads the dataset from a public API into a choropleth map. Additionally, you can change the color scheme.

This demo is also fully responsive, supports zooming ánd the map has full screen mode support. While I haven't released the code as a repo thusfar, it is open source and you can do with it whatever you want. See screenshot below...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ok, I have big data sheets that are looking like this:     <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

         Region 1 Region 2 Region...
    Date(dd.mm.yyyy) Time(24h)
    01.01.2010  0:00  123  342  565
    01.01.2010  0:15  22321  2213  2
    01.01.2010  0:30
    ...
    01.01.2010  23:45
    02.01.2010  0:00
    02.01.2010  0:15
    ...   ..

    31.12.2010  23:45

<!-- end snippet --> Now I need to pick up the date you want and the time and then my map will be created. I dont know how this can be done in html or javascript

Comment: @StefanSchaefer : Could you create a small http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate what you've got already and give more details on what is missing?